# Japanese drama about a girl haunted by a ghost of her mother's younger self

Tags: story-identification, ghost

Update: found it. It was Teru Teru Ashita 
I watched this Japanese drama years ago (10+ probably) and I've been trying to find it but can't remember the title. I remember mainly that it was about a schoolgirl that went to live with her grandmother in the countryside and was haunted by an angry ghost. Eventually she found out that the ghost is just the personification of her mother's anger when she was young. The mother is actually still alive in the present. I can't really remember much else about it.

Does anyone know what the title might be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a movie or a series?

Comment: I think it was a series but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Was it animated/anime or live-action?

Comment: @Fen - Rather than editing the answer into the question, you should post it as an actual answer using the 'Your Answer' field. That way, if the answer receives upvotes, you'll earn some reputation from it. When 48 hours have elapsed since the question was first posted, you'd also be able to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, which is this site's way of formally indicating that a question has been solved to the asker's satisfaction.